# Injecting a single dependency to a view model

Tags: swift, mvvm, viewmodel

I want the `LoginViewModel` to have a single dependency of `LoginViewModelService`.
 `LoginViewModelService` in itself cannot have an implementation.
Its methods will be implemented by both the `LoginController` and `AccountController`.

The challenge I’m having right now is, when I instantiate the `LoginViewModel` which has the single dependency of `LoginViewModelService`, there is no way I can inject `Login Controller` and the `Account Controller` as its implementation class even though they implement the methods of the `LoginViewModelService`.

To get a better idea I have attached [the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL5kA.png) from my playground.

What I hope I can do is, there is some way to accomplish the single dependency structure but if thats impossible I would like your recommendation on how I should approach this. Basically my objective is that the service being used by the `Login View Model` should not have access to method that it does not need, for example `Logout()` from the `Login Controller` class or the `delete()` from the `Account` controller class.

```
class AccountController {
    func create() {print("Create")}
    func get() {print("get")}
    func update() {print("update")}
    func delete() {print("delete")}
}
// protocol LoginController {   
// ...
// }

class LoginController {
    func apple() {print("apple")}
    func google() {print("google")}
    func phone() {print("phone")}
    func logout() {print("logout")}
}

protocol LoginViewModelService {
    func apple()
    func google()
    func phone()
    func get()
}
extension LoginViewModelService {
    func apple(){}
    func google(){}
    func phone(){}
    func get(){}
}

class ViewModel {
    init(serivice: LoginViewModelService) {}
}


let accountController = AccountController()
let loginController = LoginController()

extension AccountController: LoginViewModelService {}
extension LoginController: LoginViewModelService {}


// -------------------------This is what I hope I can do-------------
let vm = ViewModel(serivice: accountController & loginController)
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The `&` is used in inheritance and conformance. You would need a third `class` that  conforms `ThirdClass: AccountController, LoginViewModelService ` then with generics you can tell your view model that `serivice` should be `AccountController & LoginViewModelService `

Comment: Could you please give me a code example.

Comment: Not really sure I understood your goal? If you want to inject _one_ instance then you need one class combining/wrapping both those services, you cannot just glue two objects. Or ... write down more details in question, use-case, scenario, whatever more.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do. Say for example I have class named LoginViewModelSerivceImpl and implements LoginViewModelService. And I inject account controller and login controller. Then LoginViewModelSerivceImpl has access to methods that it does not need via those injections. I need a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it I came up with this solution.

```html
protocol CurrentProfileProvider {
    func getMyProfile()
}
protocol ProfileCreator {
    func create()
}
protocol ProfileUpdater {
    func update(onlyLocally: Bool)
}
protocol ProfileDeleter {
    func delete()
}

protocol ConversationCreator {
    func create()
}

protocol ListenersProvider {
    func listenersList() -> [String]
}

protocol AccountController:CurrentProfileProvider,ProfileCreator,ProfileUpdater,ProfileDeleter {}

class AccountControllerImpl:AccountController {
    func update(onlyLocally: Bool) {}
    func create() {print("Create")}
    func getMyProfile() {print("Get my profile")}
    func delete() {print("delete")}
}

protocol LoginProvider {
    func apple()
    func google()
    func phone()
}
protocol Logout {
    func logout()
}
protocol AuthenticationController: LoginProvider, Logout {}

class AuthenticationControllerImpl:AuthenticationController {
    func apple() {print("apple")}
    func google() {print("google")}
    func phone() {print("phone")}
    func logout() {print("logout")}
}
class ViewModel {
    let service: Service
    init(service: Service) {
        self.service = service
    }
}
extension ViewModel {
    class Service {
        let ac: CurrentProfileProvider
        let lc: LoginProvider
        
        init(ac: CurrentProfileProvider, lc: LoginProvider) {
            self.ac = ac
            self.lc = lc
        }
    }
}
let ac = AccountControllerImpl()
let lc = AuthenticationControllerImpl()

let service = ViewModel.Service(ac:ac ,lc: lc)
let vm = ViewModel(service: service)
```

Comment: Please share some more info on what your code does